# Can't update from conda 4.8.5 to 5.2

Tags: anaconda

I've attempted to upgrade to anaconda 5.2 from 4.8.5 using the recommended procedure here:

https://www.anaconda.com/blog/developer-blog/anaconda-distribution-5-2/

However, after packages were updated, I'm still on 4.8.5. See below. Any ideas as to why the version update didn't occur? I realize this might be tough to diagnose but perhaps others have experienced the same problem.

I did notice that the version here https://anaconda.org/anaconda/conda still points to 4.8.5

```
[kgvx167@usgbmlasprd033 ~]$ conda update conda
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.

[kgvx167@usgbmlasprd033 ~]$ conda install anaconda=5.2
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.

[kgvx167@usgbmlasprd033 ~]$ conda -V
conda 4.5.8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this was a misunderstanding on my part.

conda -V does not show you the current version of anaconda.

I ran conda install -c anaconda anaconda and see that anaconda 5.2 is downloaded and installed so I guess I'm on the latest.